# What's the best way to use IB / TWS in algortihmic trading for Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, api, asynchronous, tws

I was wondering what is the most efficient way, from a performance perspective, to use the TWS/IB API in Python? I want to compute and update my strategies based on real-time data (Python has a lot of libraries that may be helpful in contrast to Java I think) and based on that send buy/sell orders. These strategies computations may involve quite some processing time, so in that sense, I was thinking about implementing some sort of threading/concurrency (for Java it uses 3 threads if I understand correctly, see *1).

I know there is IBpy (I think it is the same only wrapped up some things for convenience). I came accross IB-insync as an alternative to threading in Python due to Python's concurrency limitations, if I understand correctly:
https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/api.html
which implements the IB API asynchronously and single-threaded.

Reading about concurrency in Python here:
https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/
async has some major advantages if I understand correctly since Python was designed using Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) (only one thread to hold the control of the Python interpreter). However, the IB-insync library may have some limitations too (but can be fixed by adapting code, as suggested below):

> If, for example, the user code spends much time in a calculation, or
> uses time.sleep() with a long delay, the framework will stop spinning,
> messages accumulate and things may go awry
>
> If a user operation takes a long time then it can be farmed out to a
> different process. Alternatively the operation can be made such that
> it periodically calls IB.sleep(0); This will let the framework handle
> any pending work and return when finished. The operation should be
> aware that the current state may have been updated during the sleep(0)
> call.
>
> For introducing a delay, never use time.sleep() but use sleep()
> instead.

Would a multi-threading solution be better just like Java (I do not know if there is a Java Async equivalent which can be combined with a lot of easy tools/libs that manipulate data)? Or should I stick to Python Async? Other suggestions are welcome, too. With regard to multiple threads in Python (and Java), the following site:

https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/connection.html

mentions (*1):

> API programs always have at least two threads of execution. One thread
> is used for sending messages to TWS, and another thread is used for
> reading returned messages. The second thread uses the API EReader
> class to read from the socket and add messages to a queue. Everytime a
> new message is added to the message queue, a notification flag is
> triggered to let other threads now that there is a message waiting to
> be processed. In the two-thread design of an API program, the message
> queue is also processed by the first thread. In a three-thread design,
> an additional thread is created to perform this task.

The phrase "The two-threaded design is used in the IB Python sample Program.py..." suggests that there are already two threads involved, which is a little bit confusion to me since the second reference mentions Python being single-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Python is **not** technically single-threaded, you can create multiple threads in Python, but there is GIL, which only allows one thread to run at a time, that is why it is sometimes said single-threaded ! But, GIL handles it so efficiently that it doesn't seem single threaded ! I have used multi-threading in Python and it is good . GIL handles all the orchestration of switching and swapping threads, but this proves to be a significance to single-threaded programs as a small speed boost, and a bit slow in multi-threaded programs .

I am also searching for a multi-threaded SDK for IB API ! I have not found one yet, except the Native one, which is a bit complicated for me .
And IB_Insync is not allowing for multi-threading :(

*Btw, I am new to Stack Overflow, so don't mind me ...*